# DFS AND BFS can someone explain this for me

Tags: pseudocode, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

```
BREADTH-FIRST-SEARCH(G,v)
 Q←new Queue()
 visited←[]
 Q.enqueue(v)
 WHILE Q is not empty
 u←q.dequeue()
 IF u is not in visited
 visited.append(u)
 FOR all edges, e, from u
 Q.enqueue(e.to)
 RETURN visited

DEPTH-FIRST-SEARCH (G, v)
 S←new Stack()
 visited←[]
 S.push(v)
 WHILE S is not empty
 u←S.pop()
 IF u is not in visited
 visited.append(u)
 FOR all edges, e, from u, S.push(e.to)
 RETURN visited
```

Can someone explain the for loop for this pseudocode, i understand everything else but the for loop has got me confused.

Comment: In BFS traversal, all children are explored first and then further children are explored. 
So we put start node in a Queue and iterate till queue is not empty. In every iteration we will add all children of current node into the Queue. Since queue has "First In First Out" property, the nodes inserted first are explored first.

In DFS, we use a stack in place of queue which has "First In Last Out" property. So one complete branch (depth) will be explored before starting with another branch.

Comment: Why the `Python` tag?

Comment: What is unclear about that? You visit the things that are linked from this node, all of them in turn.

Comment: The improper indentation is a major inhibitor for understanding, though.